# PHP Facebook SDK persistent logged user

Tags: facebook, sdk, sign

I am having a situation here. You can check my installation at: http://rs.eboxtools.com

The problem is that when I logged once I can't make a true logout. Even when I logout from Facebook I can still see my user info as if I was sign in.

Why is Facebook keep showing the same info?

In my opinion if an user choose to logout the app shouldn't accept the same user and should ask Facebook to log in a user and show only the information if user is logged in. Am I missing the point?

My direct question is. How can I definitely log out from facebook in this situation. I saw many sites like PHP Classes that just let the last user that used Login With Facebook to log in without being logged in at Facebook. This is a security problem right? That means that If I use Log in with Facebook once, even if I logout facebook and the app in question the next person that uses the same option will be logged in at my own account!!

Thanks for any help clarifying this... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case - you have to remove the PHPSESSID cookie:

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID","",time()-3600,"/");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that in the index.php and then redirect to the SDK because if you put this in SDK it stops working.

Comment: Although I've realized that if the user closes the window the security problem is deleted.

Comment: It isn't only a security thing - this may cause user experience problem too. You can use js to delete cookies too. If my answer helped you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Since I want to use multiple Social Plugins I've created a main root script that kills all cookies and sessions and then redirect to the actual script that do everything else. Neat and works all the time since most of the times when the button is used the user is different.